# how to update only one attribute in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working with mongoose version 4.1.8 below is my mongo db schema looks like this

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  const mongoose = require('mongoose');
  const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

  const DataCodeSchema = new Schema({

    label: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      maxLength: 60
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      maxLength: 255
    },

    enabled: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: true
    },


    items:{
      type:Array,
      required:false
    }
  });





  module.exports = mongoose.model('DataCode', DiscountCodeSchema);
})();
```

now patch call give me data like this

```
{'items':"dataNth"}
```

and my exiting data is something like this

```
{ 'label':'data info',
'items':['data1','data2']
}
```

after patch call it is getting like his

```
{ 'label':'data info',
    'items':['dataNth']
    }
```

But I wanted like this

```
{ 'label':'data info',
    'items':['data1','data2','dataNth']
    }
```

I have used mangoose findByIdAndUpdate like this way

```
const options = {
      new: true
    };

    if (req.body.code) {
      req.body.code = req.body.code.toLowerCase();
    }

    DataCode.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.dataId, req.body, options)
      .then(dataCode => {
        if (!dataCode) {
          return errorHandler.notFound(req, res, `No data found for id: ${req.params.dataId}`);
        }

        res.status(201).json(dataCode);
      })
      .then(null, next);
```

Please let me know how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$push` is used to update the arrays.

```
DataCode.findByIdAndUpdate(
   {_id: req.params.dataId},
   { $push: {items: 'dataNth'},
   options
)
```

you can also use $set along with it to edit other fileds

```
DataCode.findByIdAndUpdate(
       {_id: req.params.dataId},
       {$push: {items: 'dataNth'},
       {$set: req.body}
       options
    )
```